# Multiple @ConfigurationProperties validator beans in Spring environment

Tags: java, spring, validation

When using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to inject properties into a bean, Spring provides the ability to define a custom validator to validate those properties.

The `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` looks up this validator using the fixed bean name `"configurationPropertiesValidator"` and class `org.springframework.validation.Validator`.

Now assume I have a `@ConfigurationProperties` with its validator in a module A. Another module B has a dependency on module A. Module B also defines its own `@ConfigurationProperties` and its own validator.

When the app loads up, the post-processor picks up only one of these beans. This disables the other part of the validation.

Is there a solution to this? How can I keep both configuration property validators enabled in my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem and realized that `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` verifies if the class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` implements the Validator interface itself. (see `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor#determineValidator`)

So the solution is to move all property validation to the annotated property class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@ConfigurationProperties("test.properties")
@Component
public class TestProperties implements Validator {

    private String myProp;

    public String getMyProp()
    {
        return myProp;
    }

    public void setMyProp( String myProp )
    {
        this.myProp = myProp;
    }

    public boolean supports( Class<?> clazz )
    {
        return clazz == TestProperties.class;
    }

    public void validate( Object target, Errors errors )
    {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty( errors, "myProp", "myProp.empty" );

        TestProperties properties = (TestProperties) target;

        if ( !"validThing".equals( properties.getMyProp() ) ) {
            errors.rejectValue( "myProp", "Not a valid thing" );
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I also just realized that by doing that, the default `configurationPropertiesValidator` reverts back to `Jsr303ValidatorFactory` which means you can validate properties with both your custom `Validator` implementation and JSR-303 annotations:

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. It seems to just ignore my customer Validator

Comment: @Plog Your property class MUST implement Validator.